# ExpressJS - Proper way to regenerate JWT after user info changes

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Let's say that after initial launch/login, the backend sends a token to frontend containing user info such as username, email, and other credentials. This token resides in user's client and gets sent back with every API call for authentication.

At one point, the user might update their email. From then on, JWT should be regenerated so that it contains new email instead of the old one.

I can achieve this by fetching most recent data from the DB and generating a new token on every 'verifyAuth' call and it works mostly fine, but I believe a more efficient flow can be implemented.

The 'verifyAuth' middleware that I use is almost a global middleware, it is executed with almost every request and multiple times on that, so fetching data on every call significantly increases response times.

How can I make sure that JWTs are up-to-date efficiently without repeated DB queries?

```js
const verifyAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
  
    if (!authorization) {
      return res
        .status(status.unauthorized)
        .send({ ...error, message: 'No auth.' });
    }
  
    try {
      const token = authorization && authorization.split(' ')[1];
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
      const { userId } = decoded;
  
      const dbResp = await db.oneOrNone(
        `SELECT id AS user_id, username, email
          FROM users
          WHERE id = $1`,
        [userId]
      );
  
      req.user = {
        accessToken: token,
        userId,
        username: dbResp.username,
        email: dbResp.email,
      };
  
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res
        .status(status.unauthorized)
        .send({ ...error, message: 'No auth.' });
    }
};
```

```js
router.use('/api/app', verifyAuth, AppRouter);
router.use('/api/user', verifyAuth, UserRouter); // and more routers like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure that JWTs are up-to-date efficiently without repeated DB queries?

The short answer is - you can't. Once a JWT is issued, the only way to check whether it contains stale data is to verify that data with a source. But there are ways of getting around this problem:

1. You can keep the expiration of your tokens short. If your tokens expire after 5 min then this is the maximum amount of time that you will have to deal with stale data. Maybe you're ok with that.
2. Cache your calls to the DB. If you call the DB a few times during one request with the same query you can cache the results. You probably don't even need some fancy caching mechanisms, you can just keep the result of the query in memory and use it for subsequent calls to the DB.
3. You can implement a feature where you will keep a track of when a user's data has changed. For example, you set up a redis database (which is a fast key-value store) where you keep information "userId - timestamp of last data change". Then when you validate a token you can check whether it was issued before that entry you have in Redis. If true, then you call your DB for new data. Calling Redis will be much more lightweight than calling your SQL DB.